# Trying to POST data using Angular, RESTful API, from a Ionic user input interface

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, ionic-framework, ngresource

I am building a mobile application that uses Ionic as an HMI. I'm having trouble with AngularJS to make the connection between my interface and my database. I use a RESTful API that uses Node.JS, && MongoDB as a NoSQL database.

From this Ionic user interface:

- [interfaceFirstPart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpJhc.png)
- [interfaceSecondPart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhlCq.png)

The code of the Ionic user interface :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- pour charger ngResource -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="OrganisateurController">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Tests Ionic</h1>
       </ion-header-bar>
       <ion-content>
         <div class="list">

    <label class="item item-input">
   <input placeholder="Organisateur ID" type="number" name="organisateur_id" ng-model="organisateur_id" required >
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
   <input placeholder="Nom" type="text" name="nom" ng-model="nom" required >
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
   <input placeholder="Raison sociale" type="text" name="raison_sociale" ng-model="raison_sociale" required >
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
   <input placeholder="Logo" type="text" name="logo" ng-model="logo" required >
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
   <input placeholder="Nom evenement" type="text" name="nom_evenement" ng-model="nom_evenement" required >
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
   <input placeholder="Lieu" type="text" name="lieu" ng-model="lieu" required >
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
   <input placeholder="Description" type="text" name="description" ng-model="description" required >
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
   <input placeholder="Limite de participants" type="text" name="limite_particip_activ" ng-model="limite_particip_activ" required >
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
   <input placeholder="Heure de début" type="text" name="Heure_debut" ng-model="Heure_debut" required >
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
   <input placeholder="Nom d'activité" type="text" name="nom_activite" ng-model="nom_activite" required >
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
   <input placeholder="Date de l'événement" type="text" name="date" ng-model="date" required >
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
   <input placeholder="Nom parcours" type="text" name="nom_parcours" ng-model="nom_parcours" required >
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
   <input placeholder="Limit" type="number" name="limit" ng-model="limit" required >
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
   <input placeholder="Heure" type="text" name="heure" ng-model="heure" required >
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
   <input placeholder="Type'" type="text" name="type" ng-model="type" required >
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
   <input placeholder="Distance" type="number" name="distance" ng-model="distance" required >
   </label>


   <button class="button" ng-click="saveOrganisateur()">Créer mon profil Organisateur</button>
   <button class="button" ng-click="updateOrganisateur()">Update un organisateur</button>
   <button class="button" ng-click="find(organisateur_id)">Trouver un organisateur</button>
   </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

So basically, it's just a blank page with some input fields. And... A few buttons at the end. But I'm pretty confident that my problem is not about the buttons itselfs, but more about the way are written the functions that they refers to.

Now let's review my Angular code. I got all the code I did in one single file : app.js .

**app.js** :

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngResource'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

app.controller("OrganisateurController", [ '$scope', '$resource',function($scope, $resource) {
                $scope.organisateurs = [];

    $scope.saveOrganisateur = function(){
                    $scope.organisateurs.push({'organisateur_id':$scope.organisateur_id,
                    'nom': $scope.nom,
                    'raison_sociale': $scope.raison_sociale,
                    'logo': $scope.logo,'nom_evenement': $scope.nom_evenement,
                    'lieu': $scope.lieu,'description': $scope.description,
                    'limite_particip_activ': $scope.limite_particip_activ,
                    'Heure_debut': $scope.Heure_debut,
                    'nom_activite': $scope.nom_activite,
                    'date': $scope.date,
                    'nom_parcours': $scope.nom_parcours,
                    'limit': $scope.limit,
                    'heure': $scope.heure,
                    'type': $scope.type,
                    'distance': $scope.distance
                });     
                    // Create a resource class object
                    //
                    var organisateur = $resource('http://pocapi-test.apigee.net/organisateur');
                    // Call action method (save) on the class 
                    //
                    organisateur.save({
                    'organisateur_id':$scope.organisateur_id,
                    'nom': $scope.nom,
                    'raison_sociale': $scope.raison_sociale,
                    'logo': $scope.logo,'nom_evenement': $scope.nom_evenement,
                    'lieu': $scope.lieu,'description': $scope.description,
                    'limite_particip_activ': $scope.limite_particip_activ,
                    'Heure_debut': $scope.Heure_debut,
                    'nom_activite': $scope.nom_activite,
                    'date': $scope.date,
                    'nom_parcours': $scope.nom_parcours,
                    'limit': $scope.limit,
                    'heure': $scope.heure,
                    'type': $scope.type,
                    'distance': $scope.distance
                }, function(response){
                        $scope.message = response.message;
                    });

                    $scope.organisateur_id='';
                    $scope.nom='';
                    $scope.raison_sociale='';
                    $scope.logo = '';
                    $scope.nom_evenement ='';
                    $scope.lieu = '';
                    $scope.description ='';
                    $scope.limite_particip_activ ='';
                    $scope.Heure_debut ='';
                    $scope.nom_activite ='';
                    $scope.date ='';
                    $scope.nom_parcours ='';
                    $scope.limit ='';
                    $scope.heure ='';
                    $scope.type ='';
                    $scope.distance ='';

    }

    $scope.updateOrganisateur = function(){                         
                    // Create a resource class object
                    //
                    var organisateur = $resource('http://pocapi-test.apigee.net/organisateur/:organisateurId', {organisateurId:'@id'});
                    // Create an instance of User resource
                    // By the way I don't know what to put here as organisateurId to get my shit to work 
                    var organisateur = Organisateur.query({organisateurId:25}); 
                    // Update the new values entered in the form fields
                    //
                    organisateur.id = $scope.organisateur_id;
                    organisateur.nom = $scope.nom;                
                    organisateur.raison_sociale = $scope.raison_sociale;
                    organisateur.logo = $scope.logo;
                    organisateur.nom_evenement = $scope.nom_evenement;
                    organisateur.lieu = $scope.lieu;
                    organisateur.description = $scope.description;
                    organisateur.limite_particip_activ = $scope.limite_particip_activ;
                    organisateur.Heure_debut = $scope.Heure_debut;
                    organisateur.nom_activite = $scope.nom_activite;
                    organisateur.date = $scope.date;
                    organisateur.nom_parcours = $scope.nom_parcours;
                    organisateur.limit = $scope.limit;
                    organisateur.heure = $scope.heure;
                    organisateur.type = $scope.type;
                    organisateur.distance = $scope.distance;
                    // Call '$' prefixed action menthod to post ("save" )
                    //
                    organisateur.$save = function(response){
                        $scope.message = response.message;
                    };
                    // Push the new objects in the $scope.users                     
                    //
                    $scope.organisateurs.push({
                    'organisateur_id':$scope.organisateur_id,
                    'nom': $scope.nom,
                    'raison_sociale': $scope.raison_sociale,
                    'logo': $scope.logo,'nom_evenement': $scope.nom_evenement,
                    'lieu': $scope.lieu,'description': $scope.description,
                    'limite_particip_activ': $scope.limite_particip_activ,
                    'Heure_debut': $scope.Heure_debut,
                    'nom_activite': $scope.nom_activite,
                    'date': $scope.date,
                    'nom_parcours': $scope.nom_parcours,
                    'limit': $scope.limit,
                    'heure': $scope.heure,
                    'type': $scope.type,
                    'distance': $scope.distance
                });     

                    $scope.organisateur_id='';
                    $scope.nom='';
                    $scope.raison_sociale='';
                    $scope.logo = '';
                    $scope.nom_evenement ='';
                    $scope.lieu = '';
                    $scope.description ='';
                    $scope.limite_particip_activ ='';
                    $scope.Heure_debut ='';
                    $scope.nom_activite ='';
                    $scope.date ='';
                    $scope.nom_parcours ='';
                    $scope.limit ='';
                    $scope.heure ='';
                    $scope.type ='';
                    $scope.distance ='';    
                 }
}]);
```

Now, I am going to show you how the   REAL   MongoDB object - ( the one i'm actually getting with Ionic && the Angular code doesn't look like that ! ) - I want to post looks like. Because the data's I got in my scope are not in the real format, as I am totally not sure about how to type it without messing up my code.

How it looks in code :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "58496c312d7e130bbc94853b",
    "organisateur_id": 1,
    "nom": "LEROUX",
    "raison_sociale": "Manager",
    "logo": "DECATHLON",
    "evenement": [
      {
        "nom_evenement": "Cap sur le Sport",
        "lieu": "Cesson-Sévigné, Placis Vert",
        "description": "Quelle équipe sera la meilleure de Cap ? Nous le saurons durant ces difficiles conditions de Décembre !",
        "limit_particip_activ": "150",
        "Heure_debut": "15:00",
        "activites": [
          {
            "nom_activite": "Tennis pour tous",
            "date": "21/12/2016",
            "parcours": [
              {
                "nom_parcours": "DoubleField",
                "limit": 16,
                "heure": "15:30",
                "type": "Tennis",
                "distance": 0
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How it looks in my MongoDB database :

[image: mongoDBOrganisateurObject]

Now, this is what It posts in my MongoDB database when I use the Ionic button "Créer mon profil". As a reminder, that button refers to the function saveOrganisateur() :

[image: ionicSendThatToMongoDB]

Here we are, I think I said everything you needed to know so you could help me !
If you need any more informations or have questions about the files I linked or the documents I showed you, don't hesitate to hit me up and I will answer rapidly.
I will check the page ~every @30 minutes.

1. how do I post my data from Ionic, to my database without my object being empty on every line ?
2. if we get it to work, how can I format my code to post the data in the real format of the object, with the "{", "}", "[", & "]".

Comment: Welcome to SO, If you want to have a chance that SO-users will help you, please, remove the story at the beginning and go right to your problem(s). A simple 'Thank you' at the end is enough. Did you really read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before writing your Question ?

Comment: Thank you for your review i'm changing that in a few minutes

Comment: I removed some of the editorializing from the first paragraph.

Comment: I turn off my API for the night. Thank you for the attention given